# Suppress labels of rank abundance curves

Tags: r, graph

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to suppress the labels of rank abundance curves with rankabundance {BiodiversityR}. Using the example code from the documentation:

```
library(vegan)
data(dune.env)
data(dune)
RankAbun.1 <- rankabundance(dune)
RankAbun.1
rankabunplot(RankAbun.1,scale='abundance', addit=FALSE, specnames=c(1,2,3))
#works fine
rankabuncomp(dune, y=dune.env, factor='Management', scale='proportion',   legend=FALSE)
#try to suppress labels
rankabuncomp(dune, y=dune.env, factor='Management', scale='proportion', legend=FALSE, labels=FALSE)
```

Rank abundance curves with labels:

[image: Rank abundance curves with labels]

When I try to suppress labels, I get the following error code:

> Error in rankabunplot(rankabundance(x, y, factor, levels[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL7lB.png)), scale = scale:
>     formal argument "labels" matched by multiple actual arguments.

I've tried `labels=FALSE`, `labels=""`, `labels="n"` and get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the source for that function it seems like there is no option to disable the labels. Of course you can get around that by modifying the function.

If you type `rankabuncomp` in the console it will print the source for the function. Copy everything that is output and then in the console enter `newrankabuncomp <-` and paste the source. Before you hit enter go through and change any of the places where it says `labels = levels[1]` or `labels = levels[i]` to `labels = ''`

Then run `newrankabuncomp(dune, y=dune.env, factor='Management', scale='proportion', legend=FALSE)`